# How to install last version of Evolution in Debian Gnome ?

Tags: debian, evolution

By default, debian gnome come with Evolution 3.12. I would like to upgrade to the last version available 3.18.

I download the source package and proceed with a

> # download source
> wget https://download.gnome.org/sources/evolution/3.18/evolution-3.18.0.tar.xz
>
> # decompress
> tar xf *.tar.xz
>
> # start setup
> ./configure

and it give a error message which indicate me there is a package version error.

```
...
configure: error: Package requirements (camel-1.2 >= 3.18.0
 libebook-1.2 >= 3.18.0
 libecal-1.2 >= 3.18.0
 libedataserver-1.2 >= 3.18.0
 libedataserverui-1.2 >= 3.18.0
 libebackend-1.2 >= 3.18.0) were not met:

 Requested 'camel-1.2 >= 3.18.0' but version of camel is 3.12.9
 Requested 'libebook-1.2 >= 3.18.0' but version of libebook is 3.12.9
 Requested 'libecal-1.2 >= 3.18.0' but version of libecal is 3.12.9
 Requested 'libedataserver-1.2 >= 3.18.0' but version of          libedataserver is 3.12.9
 No package 'libedataserverui-1.2' found
 Requested 'libebackend-1.2 >= 3.18.0' but version of libebackend is 3.12.9
```

How could I solve this ?

Comment: If you want recent software, Debian is not the best choice for a distribution. You will have to replace far more than Evolution to get this to work.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to run the latest Evolution on an older distribution of Linux is to use Flatpak:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution/#Evolution_in_Flatpak